# making this linq query faster

Tags: c#, linq

I need the most efficient way to get the value of the searchName, or if null return searchName.  I am returning just a single string, so maybe I should search itemRepository.Item instead of Items

```
return itemRepository.Items()
                    .Where(i => i.Name.Contains(searchName))
                    .Select(i => i.Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault() ?? searchName;
```

Comment: Why is `Items` a method rather than a property (as evidenced by the `()`)? Other than that question, this seems exactly the canonical way I'd do what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah it is a bit weird, but its calling an API, which returns a set of Items, I can also pass in a filter and a sort to the method.  I just feel like I am looping one too many times

Comment: 1. You should not be concerned with the internal workings of LINQ - the designers have gone through great lengths to make it as optimal as possible. There are no direct loops in your code.

2. That being said, I only see a single loop - the one that goes over all items and pulls out the `Value` of those that contain `searchName` in its `Name`.

Comment: You can combine the `.Select()` and the `.FirstOrDefault()`, but other than that, there's nothing else you can do to this query.

Comment: @Bobson combine them how?

Comment: ah right, looks good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as `Items()` returns an `IQueryable<Item>` directly from the database, then this code is just about as fast as you can get it. If not, I think your `Items()` method will be the main bottleneck in this code.

From your comment it sounds like `Items()` is indeed trying to do more work than necessary. You should either directly reference the `IQueryable` collection of the repository and bypass the `Items()` method *or* focus your efforts on improving the efficiency of that method.